# VK_KHR_ray_tracing_pipeline supported by which AMD GPUs on Linux?

Tags: vulkan, raytracing, amd-gpu

Is there a comprehensive list, where i can check the supported Vulkan extensions for all AMD GPUs? I have been looking all over the internet, but can't find any information on this.
I currently have a RX570, but I thought the Vulkan API would feature a fallback mode for cards lacking hardware acceleration.

I think i installed the `amdgpu-driver` correctly, but when I try to run the `raytracing_simple` [example](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples), it says that the RX570 is lacking the requested extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMD introduced ray tracing support with the RX 6x00 series. A fallback mode for older hardware would have to be implemented by the vendor, which is not the case on AMD. So you need a RX 6x00 GPU for doing hardware accelerated ray tracing on Linux.

You can check `VK_KHR_ray_tracing_pipeline` support on Linux here: https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listdevicescoverage.php?extension=VK_KHR_ray_tracing_pipeline&platform=linux

That's a Vulkan hardware database I'm maintaining, which also has listings for extension support on different platforms. The data provided there is from user-uploaded reports. While not an official Vulkan database, thanks to regular contributions it's mostly complete and gives a good overview on Vulkan support for different hardware.

Note: As mentioned above, reports are submitted by users, so the list may not be 100% complete.

Comment: I already was searching your database (really awesome contribution, thank you very much!) and only found the "AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT" listed. I hoping it was just incomplete.
Do you happen to know if AMD is planing on delivering a fallback mode, similar to what NVIDIA has done for their older GTX cards?
I find it quite difficult to find information on this from official sources.

Comment: Not that I'm aware. NVIDIA's fall back was nice for developing but ultimately slow. I don't think AMD will do something similar, but then again I'm no AMD employee.

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward to several years in the future since this was posted, and AMD didn't implement a fallback, but the open source developers did in Linux.  The ray tracing support on AMD cards only uses 1 or 2 new GPU instructions to access the ray tracing hardware, so on older cards they copy-pasted over the ray tracing support in the drivers but where it would spit out those ray tracing instructions it spits out a drop-in replacement bit of shader code.  Slower but identical results.

Oh and to answer your question directly -- this is for Linux but if you go to mesamatrix.net there is in fact a big set of tables for Vulkan 1.3/1.2/1.1/1.0, extensions not part of any Vulkan version, and similar for OpenGL, for all drivers in Mesa (i.e. the couple Intel & AMD drivers for older and newer models, Noveau Nvidia driver, and ones for Qualcomm and a few other phone/tablety-type drivers.. which shockingly now also support Vulkan and such.)